# notification after a process in background terminates

Tags: shell, unix

I am a newbie to shell scripting.

I have several programs running in the background on different host machines (say host1, host2, host3....). Are there any ways that I can get a notification (maybe by email) whenever a program terminates in any of the host machine?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. The programs are already running now. Shall I suspend them beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
wait PID ; mail -s "PID ended" toto@tuto.com
```

Comment: What if there are multiple background processes?

Comment: I don't have access to a linux console right now, something like `for p in PIDLIST; do (wait $p ; mail ... ) & ; done` shall work

Answer (score 0):

You can use at command:

For more details check the man page of [at](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at)